# What is best approach for a WPF re-usable search text box?

Tags: wpf, templates, search, user-controls, reusability

I have a textbox with a search icon next to it inside of a dockpanel that I use in every page of mine. I plan on hooking up the click of the search icon to a command and on each page it brings up the same popup with a listview, whose contents vary from page to page based on the viewmodel binding.

I would like to be able to centralize this text+search control so I can re-use the control and include it in each with a line or 2 of code - the inclusion such as  and the line for binding to a different search method (if necessary).

What is the best way to do this? Create a custom  or use some kind of template approach?

Please advise and if possible, describe the design and provide an example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try a  UserControl?

Comment: Probably what I will go with, but want to know if there is a template based approach as well. Let's say I run into a need to customize the control's front end slightly in some instances, I'm not sure the UserControl approach will allow that.

Comment: Personally I would go with a custom `UserControl`, as you want the same consistant UI functionality in many places. As for your concern about customizing the UI for some variations of the control, it depends on what kind of customizations you want to do. In most cases, I would probably use a Property or DependencyProperty to trigger the various UI changes.